Inequality regarding expectations
I have a simple question that somehow eludes me. Namely: is it always true that for an integrable r.v. $X$ and some sigma-algebra $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is from a filtered probability space $(Ω, \mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_t, P)$ we always have
$E(|X|  |\mathcal{H}) \geq | E(X |\mathcal{H})|$
It seems very intuitive to hold given that it holds for a regular, non-conditional expectation, but I'm not able to prove it rigorously. Any help would be appreciated.

Please don't forget to mark the question as answered

It follows immediately by linearity. Specifically, we know that
$$E(a X + b Y | \mathcal{H}) = a E(X| \mathcal{H}) + b E(X|\mathcal{H}).$$
Now, observe that
$$|E(X|\mathcal{H})| = |E(X^+|\mathcal{H}) - E(X^-|\mathcal{H})| \leq E(X^+|\mathcal{H}) + E(X^-|\mathcal{H}) = E(|X| |\mathcal{H}),$$
where I used the triangle inequality. For those not familiar with the notation $X^+, X^-$ see this.

If $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathbb P)$, and $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal A$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal A$, then $\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[ X \mid \mathcal B\right] \right\rvert \leq \mathbb E\left[ \lvert X \rvert \mid \mathcal B\right]$. The proof goes just as Oscar described. See for example, p. 232, Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes, by Le Gall.
Also, if $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_+$ is convex, and $X \in L^1$, then $\mathbb E\left[ f(X) \mid \mathcal B\right] \geq f\left( \mathbb E\left[ X \mid \mathcal B\right] \right)$. This proof is different and more complicated than the one above. Specifically, you define
\begin{align*}
E_f := \left\{ (a, b) \in \mathbb R^2 \colon \forall x \in \mathbb R, f(x) \geq ax + b\right\},
\end{align*}
and then note that $f(x) = \sup_{(a, b) \in E_f \cap \mathbb Q^2}(ax + b)$. See p. 236 of the same book, and/or p. 211 of Probability: Theory and Examples, by Durrett.
